# How to create a button in a jsp page, that submits all forms on that page to their resp. form action

Tags: forms, jsp

I have a JSP web page where multiple forms are shown at a time. I want to create one button that submits all forms to their respective actions. Can this be done? How to implement this? All the forms belong to different 3rd party sites.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can do this using Ajax **Or** you can loop through all forms on page in javascript or jQuery and then submit them one by one. Give every form a target frame so that you can monitor response.

Comment: is it possible to hide the response (after a form is submitted)... i want my code to go through the response and determine if the submission was successful (I already have with me all possible success/failure messages for that submission with me)... this has to be done in a GAE web application...

Comment: Not really but you can use `style="display:none"` on target frame it is not visible on page and then after form submission completes check for data in it in javascript and do appropriate operation. This can be a dirty work to do. =(

Answer (score 2):

Ajax post. For example, use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and the [jQuery Form](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/) plugin.

Then something like this to submit all forms with a button click

```
<input type="button" value="Submit all" id="submitAll">

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submitAll').click(function() {
            $('form').ajaxSubmit({
                success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                    alert('form submitted, return status:' + statusText);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```